# Android Studio 1.1.0 Facebook SDK Login

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, sdk

I try to test the login with facebook SDK.

So I add with `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'`.

Then add `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());` 
to MainActivity.java

**But when I add**

```
 <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />`
```

**I have this following error** :

```
Rendering Problems The following classes could not be instantiated:
com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton (Open Class, Show Exception)
Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE  
Exception Details java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:806)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385) Copy stack to clipboard
```

Answer (score 22):

You didn't posted your Activity code. But i think your code is like:

```
setContentView(R.layout.my_login_layout);
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
```

The problem is the order of the code. Ignore the "Render problems" in the layout, change the order of the code to this:

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create(); // this line doesn't matter 
setContentView(R.layout.my_login_layout);
```

Use this code in OnCreate(...) { ... }

**Avoid layout render problems**

if you want to solve the render problems (layout preview) check the [@Nathan30 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29268738/android-studio-1-1-0-facebook-sdk-login/29354870#29354870) (see below).

1. Download Facebook SDK
2. Import it as a *Module* to your project
3. Then add `<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton .../>` to your layout.

Comment: But it's very annoying the render problems, there is no solution for this ?

Comment: I'm not sure right now how i can avoid this... because you're right is very annoying. If i find a way, i will update the answer.

Comment: This actually makes a lot of sense. I had the exact same issue. Cheers.
I reckon the new Facebook SDK will have some render elements... The same happens with Google+

Answer (score 3):

Simply specifying a different version of Facebook SDK worked for me.
Adjust the `build.graddle` file dependencies part. 
Mine looks like;

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.4.0'}
```

Version 4.0.0 persistently threw the exception

I did not have to import the Facebook SDK as a module

I had to play around with the different versions of the SDK as available [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.facebook.android/facebook-android-sdk)

Answer (score 2):

**Simple, quick and easy:** update the SDK version on `Gradle` -> `Dependencies` to the latest version and the rendering problem is solved. At the time of writing this, the latest Facebook SDK is 4.3.0, so this is what it should look like on `Dependencies`:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.3.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who have this problem of rendering, I find a solution. I don't use anymore the gradle.build dependencies to the facebook SDK. I download the SDK from the website of Facebook, and I import the module into my project in Android Studio. Then, add

```
<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/authButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp" />
```

to your layout xml

Comment: Good news!... i don't like to import projects as a modules but if this solves the problem, is good to know.

Comment: i updated my answer for people with the same issue... :)

Answer (score -2):

I tried this and it works

Added this in dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.4.0'
}
```

[image]

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        CallbackManager callbackManager;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
            callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);


            return true;
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: And in the render layout it display the button correcltly or the same problem as me ?